# DD image smaller than drive copied

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, dd, gzip

I took a backup of my server's OS disk through a live USB. Using the command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=(30 gb worth of sectors) conv=noerror,sync status=progress | gzip -c > /path/to/removable/media
```

The command completed with no errors and the image was created. The img.gz is 16 GB

(The server's OS takes up ~15gb of storage) but when I open the .gz in winrar it tells me that the contents are only 2.21 GB and yet the archive is 16 GB.

Does this mean there was an error in the backup process or is it normal for the archive to be larger than the image inside it?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bug in winrar.

Comment: So would it be safe for me to assume that I can use this backup in the event of a disk failure?

Comment: Extract it then check with rsync.

Comment: The only backup safe to use useuse one you've successfully tested a restore from. So, try that. Restore somewhere (a VM?) and see if it works. Side note, I wouldn't specify a `count` if I wanted a full disk. How big is your server's drive? Not space used but full size.

Comment: @Bob The drive is 500gb and I gave my last spare HDD to a friend so I didn't have anywhere to dump the file that could accommodate a 500gb image. Since the os is only ~15 gb of space, I specified a count that would equal 30gb of sectors just to be safe

Comment: @IporSircer okay, Im extracting the image with winrar. I'm unfamiliar with rsync but I do have some samba shares setup on the server. What should I do to check it with rsync?

Comment: Yea, that's not how filesystems work: there's no guarantee that your data exists in the first 30 GB of the drive. I'll write up an answer with alternatives when I get back to a pc in a bit.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for your help so far. I'm currently converting the raw image file into a .vdi. If it doesn't work Ill buy a drive that can accommodate the full size dd dump. Ill post my results with VirtualBox. I completely forgot about the possibility of disk fragmentation. Guess I shouldn't be doing these things when im tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Backups

Firstly, some advice on backups in general: you cannot rely on a backup until you have tested and verified that your restore process works. There are a few methods for testing backups:

- A full restore to physical hardware, if you have the hardware handy and it's a critical backup.
- A full restore to a virtual machine, if you're lacking spare hardware.
- Extracting data and verifying correctness and completeness, if you don't care about restoring a bootable OS.

I generally would not consider checking uncompressed size with WinZip to be particularly useful. However, the results you obtained *could* indicate that you have supplied an incorrect `count` , which brings us to...

---

### Issues with your `dd` command

> ```
> count=(30 gb worth of sectors)
> ```

My first thought on seeing this is that you should never be specifying a `count` when backing up a drive. If you wanted to back up a specific partition, you should use a partition block device (`/dev/sdXN` where `N` is a number). Otherwise, you should just let `dd` take the whole drive; by specifying a `count` you risk (in fact, almost guarantee) that you'll be discarding data and possibly corrupting the filesystem.

In a comment, you supplied the reasoning:

> The drive is 500gb and I gave my last spare HDD to a friend so I didn't have anywhere to dump the file that could accommodate a 500gb image. Since the os is only ~15 gb of space, I specified a count that would equal 30gb of sectors just to be safe

Unfortunately, that's not how filesystems work. Most filesystems do not guarantee that all data will be stored towards the beginning of the drive.

---

### Alternatives

There's a few other ways to do what you want.

#### Archiving files/data only

If you only want a data backup and don't care too much about being able to restore a bootable OS, you can back up files only with the `tar` command. This means you'll still have your data, but you'll have to reinstall an OS from scratch and manually recover the data (and any installed applications).

1. Copy *files* to an archive with `tar` piped to `gzip`.

#### Compressed backups with zeroed free space

This is more or less what you have already attempted. You have the right idea with `gzip`: hopefully it'll compress any unused space (*very* compressible) to nothing. You just need to drop the `count` from your command.

Unfortunately, this will not necessarily work out because deleted files may still exist on disk and will not appear as empty to `gzip`. Therefore, you should [clear unused space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4) first. Your backup process becomes:

1. Clear unused space with `zerofree` or similar
2. Copy the drive to a compressed image with `dd` (without `count`!) piped through `gzip`

#### Use a tool that backs up used blocks only, e.g. `partclone`

Some tools exist, like `partclone`, that are smart enough to recognise and only back up used blocks. The [Arch wiki has some examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partclone) on usage with `gzip`, and the [manual](https://partclone.org/usage/partclone.php) has some examples down the bottom. This effectively replaces `dd` in your pipeline.

You will need to use the same tool again when restoring data.

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked this aspect of filesystems completely. I have confirmed that there is a fault in the image as when it is loaded into Virtualbox I get a grub rescue prompt and trying to ls the /boot directory results in a "Read/Write outside of HD0" error. I appreciate your well written response to my question and I'll redo the backup tomorrow after a night of good sleep.